# How Can I Use Google fitness Api to access heart rate sensor?

Tags: java, android, api

Now, I'm working on smartwatch application that recording heart rate and send heart rate results to cloud to do some processing, but I faced some problems during development process because I want to build application from scratch like deal with PPG signal and do processing it by implement Digital signal processing. However, I didn't have time to do all that because I need to learn many things to do something like that because that I was searching on API to help me to build my app in sample way. Then, I found Google Fitness API, and I already import it in Android studio But I didn't know from where I need to start and how to deal with heart rate sensor and how to access heart rate sensor and how can I take results for sensor? I want to know anything can help me to access sensor and deal with sensor data in clear way to access heart rate sensor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Sensors section in Google Fitness API Documentations.

- Access Raw Sensor Data
- Use Bluetooth Sensors
- Support Additional Sensors

Take a peek:
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors